# I want to help file .Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching

For example, my web link is `domain.com/link-web-1234.html` 
I used to save the file cache folder `domain.com/cached/link-web-1234.html`

I wish if the `link domain.com/link-web-1234.html users,` if they exist `domain.com/cached/link-web-1234.html` file contents are taken in that cache file!

If not exist, then run as normal!

I must write. Ht access as any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /cached%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```